# Keycloak : Customize claim "scope" to "scp"

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, keycloak, openid

I would like to modify the token claim scope to scp in keycloak. I tried with add mappers but it did not work.

If you have an idea on that ?

For information, I tried on keycloak version 22.0.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,